# integration of Black Body radiation with python

Tags: python, physics, astronomy

I am trying to plot the integration of Black Body radiation. But for some reason there's the little blimp on the graph. I also get the warning.

> IntegrationWarning: The algorithm does not converge.  Roundoff error
> is detected

Which I think might be over estimating the integration. But I am unsure how to resolve this issue.

```
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import numpy as np                 #math module 

import matplotlib                  #Plotting module 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
#constants
h = 6.626e-34
c = 3.0e+8
k = 1.38e-23           # Boltzmann constant
T = range(1, 6000)
plot = []

for t in T:
    integrand = lambda x : (((2*h*(c**2))/(x**5))*(1/(np.exp((h*c)/(x*k*t))-1)))
    result,err = integrate.quad(integrand, 0, np.inf, epsabs=0, limit=50)
    plot.append(result)
                
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))        #Create a figure of a certain size
plt.plot(T,plot)                      #Make a plot in the figure.
plt.xlabel('Temperature K', fontsize=14)       #X Label 
plt.ylabel('Intensity (W/sr m^3)', fontsize=14)       #Y label
plt.title("Plank's Formula over all spectra")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my fix for this:

Basically, instead of integrating from 0 to np.inf, I integrate from a small value to a large value. I pick the small value and large values `lambda_min` and `lambda_max` to be 100x smaller/larger (using `width`) than the reference lambda, which is when h * c / labmda = k_B * T.

Also, I plot the exact integral of the balckbody curve: sigma * T^4 as a line, and they lay on top of each other. You can increase `width` for a more accurate integral

```
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import numpy as np                 #math module 

import matplotlib                  #Plotting module 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.ion()
#constants
h = 6.626e-34
c = 3.0e+8
k = 1.38e-23           # Boltzmann constant
sigma = 5.6704e-8      #For later
width = 100            #For integrating. Increase for more accuracy
T = range(1, 6000)
plot = []

for t in T:
    lambda_rel = h * c / (k * t)     #defining the reference lambda
    lambda_min = lambda_rel / width  #Defining lower int bound
    lambda_max = lambda_rel * width  #Defining upper int bound
    integrand = lambda x : (((2*h*(c**2))/(x**5))*(1/(np.exp((h*c)/(x*k*t))-1)))
    result,err = integrate.quad(integrand, lambda_min, lambda_max, epsabs=0, limit=50)
    plot.append(result)
                
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))        #Create a figure of a certain size
plt.plot(T,plot, 'r-')                      #Make a plot in the figure.
plt.plot(T, sigma * T**4, 'b-')    # Here I also plot the exact integral of the blackbody curve
plt.xlabel('Temperature K', fontsize=14)       #X Label 
plt.ylabel('Intensity (W/sr m^3)', fontsize=14)       #Y label
plt.title("Plank's Formula over all spectra")
```